# Adding annotations from a KML file to an MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, cllocation

I am trying to load data from a KML file over to an MKMapView.  I was able to parse the data into an array and now I am trying to create annotations on the map for each item.

Using the code below, I was able to create annotations on the map but the location is not correct:

```
Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser.rowName = @"Placemark";
parser.elementNames = @[@"name", @"address", @"coordinates", @"description"];
[parser parse];

//parseItem is an array returned with all data after items are parsed.
for (NSDictionary *locationDetails in parser.parseItems) {
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.title = locationDetails[@"name"];
    NSArray *coordinates = [locationDetails[@"coordinates"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinates[0] floatValue], [coordinates[1] floatValue]);

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

}
```

Comment: After the `annotation.title = ...` line, add this NSLog and see what it says: `NSLog(@"coords=%@", locationDetails[@"coordinates"]);`

Comment: Lists all the coordinates from the parsed data:
ie:
coords=-73.96300100000001,40.682846,0

Comment: Looks like the coordinates are coming in longitude,latitude order but the CLLocationCoordinate2DMake function takes latitude,longitude.  Try `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinates[1] doubleValue], [coordinates[0] doubleValue])`.  (Also change float to double for more accurate placement.)

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. Post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the NSLog of the coordinates was:

> coords=-73.96300100000001,40.682846,0

So it looks like the coordinates are coming in longitude,latitude order but the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` function takes latitude,longitude.

Unless the coordinates are *supposed* to be in Antarctica instead of New York City, try:

```
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                           [coordinates[1] doubleValue], 
                           [coordinates[0] doubleValue]);
```

Also note you should change `floatValue` to `doubleValue` for more accurate placement (it will also match the type of `CLLocationDegrees` which is a synonym for `double`).